# How to remove grub entries with sed?

Tags: linux, sed, grub

I need know how to remove entries in grub.cfg with sed
In my case i want remove Windows 10 entrie on sda3 and that is a multiline entrie

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

`sed -i "/menuentry 'Windows 10 (on \/dev\/sda3/,/}/d" grub.cfg`

**INI Menu entry to remove** -> `menuentry 'Windows 10 (on \/dev\/sda3`

**END Menu entry to remove** -> `}`

I used this `"` with sed because `'` is part of the entry